# Django admin loads view template when url pattern is same as model name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-2.0

I'm writing my first `Django` project in `Django 2.0`.

I noticed another weird behavior with `Django` `urlpatterns`.

I have an app `starrednotes` and model within it as `Starred(models.Model)`

same is the case with `Shared(models.Model)` within `sharednotes` app

I have configured the `urlpattern` for with path pattern same as the model name

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^starred/$', StarredNotes.as_view(), name='starred'),
    url(r'^shared/$', SharedNotes.as_view(), name='shared'),
]
```

and view `StarredNotes` is

```
class StarredNotes(ListView):
    template_name = 'notes/starred.html'
    model = Starred
    context_object_name = 'starred_notes'

    def get_queryset(self):
        starred_notes = Starred.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return starred_notes

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The URL setup above is accessible using

```
http://example.com/notes/shared
http://example.com/notes/starred
```

But when I'm accessing these two models from `admin` with URL as

```
http://example.com/admin/sharednotes/shared
http://example.com/admin/starrednotes/starred
```

These two links are loading the template setup in the `StarredNotes` and `SharedNotes` class instead of admin template.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Django? Sometimes it can solve some weird problems, like this one.

Comment: I tried reinstalling. No success.

Comment: Could you add a print screen?

Comment: Of course, I can, but the print screen of which page? The page I'm talking about is the completely blank white screen. I'm attaching that here.

Comment: please read `Edit 2`. I am facing same weired problem with another model.

Comment: @DanMoica, I have updated question with changed title and content. I have figured out the cause of this weird behaviour.

Comment: @AnujTBE the domain example.com is not a working website domain. It exists only to give it as an example. Maybe you can follow again the Django tutorial and see what is it that you missed.

Comment: domain `example.com` is just to represent the http domain of django project. The project is still in local machine and is accessible using `http://127.0.0.1:1234/` and `example.com` is replacement for the same

Comment: @AnujTBE You say you figured out the cause. Are you aware that you can post an answer to your own question?

Comment: I can, But I think it's the hard way I have figured out or its a bug in Django. Why can't we have url patter same as model name?. Anyway I will post answer by today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand why it is behaving like this. Is it a Django limitation or bug in Django.

Anyway here are two ways you can get rid of it.

**1. Change `urlpattern`**

change URL pattern and replace the pattern with something other than the model name.
*In my case, this is how my urlpatterns looks now.*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^starred/$', StarredNotes.as_view(), name='starred'),
    url(r'^shared/$', SharedNotes.as_view(), name='shared'),
]
```

**2. Change model name**

This is not the recommended way but you can rename your model to something else only if urlpattern is more important than the model. *Changing model name may require changes to many other places as well.*

```
class SharedNote(models.Model):
    # model fields

class StarredNote(models.Model):
    # model fields
```